# How to create pagination on archive.php template

Tags: pagination, archives

I'm creating a custom theme and I'm struggling to get pagination working on my archive.php template.

I've tried to adapt the code I'm using on my main blog page, but it's simply displaying all blog posts rather than just those with a certain tag or category.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong and how to get the archive.php template working as it should be WITH pagination?

Thanks in advance,

Tom

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <!-- PAGE INTRODUCTION -->
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="page_title"><?php the_archive_title(); ?></h1>
    </div>

    <!-- PAGE CONTENTS -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php 
                $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $custom_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => 10,
                    'paged' => $paged
                );
                $custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_args ); 
            ?>
            <?php if( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : while( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="item">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>

        <!-- PAGINATION -->
        <?php
            if (function_exists(custom_pagination)) {
                custom_pagination($custom_query->max_num_pages,"",$paged);
            }
        ?>

    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to make a new `WP_Query` on archive pages, if you're displaying the main loop.. Just display the posts that already fetched from the database by the main WordPress query that runs automatically on page load. Pagination would also conflict with the main query, e.g. if it had 2 pages only, and yet your custom query had 3 or more pages.

Comment: If you wanted to filter the posts in the main query, e.g. to display just 5 posts (instead of the default one - 10), you could just use the `pre_get_posts` hook to modify the main query's args.

Comment: Use `pre_get_posts` to modify the main query to get what you want and use a standard post loop instead of  creating a brand new loop with a custom `WP_Query` that has the parameters you wanted. Then the official pagination functions will work. What you're doing right now doubles the amount of work WP has to do and doubles the queries it makes, and introduces lots of new problems

Answer (score 1):

The solution was surprisingly simple as you can see below.

Thanks for your help @Sally CJ and @Tom J Nowell.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- PAGE INTRODUCTION -->
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="page_title"><?php the_archive_title(); ?></h1>
</div>

<!-- PAGE CONTENTS -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <!-- POSTS -->
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="item">
                <h3 class="subtitle no_margin_bottom"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

        <!-- PAGINATION -->
        <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>

    </div>
</div><!-- END OF SECTION -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```