# How to divide Subcategories into pages of parent category wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, categories, custom-taxonomy, query

suppose I have sturucture like this:

**Justin Bieber > Albums > Justice**

when I visit on https://example.com/category/justin-bieber/albums/

It is showing all albums of Justin Bieber category. but the problem is that

**If I have 1 Million albums(subcategories) of specific artists(parent category) then I will display that Million albums(subcategories) in one page that is what I dont want.**

I want to divide that albums into multiple pages but dont know how to do that?

Comment: Use a `taxonomy-albums.php` template and custom query to limit number of albums to display and use pagination.

Comment: I am noob of doing this. Please can you provide me code of How to  do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is called pagination.  If you [search StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pagination), you will find a bunch of questions and answers about it, like [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/400983/how-to-create-pagination-on-archive-php-template) which seems to be for what you are looking.